# Create Report with the segmentation based on the attributes in the sendable data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I wonder that if there is any reports in Salesforce Marketing Cloud to view the email performance(e.g. click rates) with the segmentation based on the attributes in the sendable data extension.

For example, there is a field - gender in the sendable data extension. I want to see the email performance for Males and Female.

I guess the data query can be used to achieve my purpose but I just wonder if there is built-in interface in the Report section so that I can generate a report easily.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing out of the box, unfortunately. Due to the open-ended nature of data schemas built with DEs, its hard to have a solution that will work for everybody when everybodys DEs are different.

You said it - A query utilizing data views such as _enterpriseAttribute, _click, _open etc would be the only way short of a custom report.